# Try-Catch in Program.cs only works when started from visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, try-catch

I tried to write a little crash reporter for uncatched expetions. This works perfectly when starting my App in VS.
But as soon as I try to start the .exe it only shows me the standard "There is an uncaught expetion"-thingy from windows.
And no it's not the crashreporter which crashes.

This is my code in the Program.cs

```
        try
        {
            Application.Run(new TestServer());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Application.Run(new CrashReporter(e.StackTrace.ToString()));
        }
    }
```

Comment: `StackTrace` is already a string.  You should pass `e.ToString()` so that you can report the actual problem.

Comment: Can you post the CrashReporter class code?

Comment: How do you know it's not the CrashReporter? Try adding `MessageBox.Show(e.ToString())` first and see if it shows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because you use a debugger.  Winforms detects this and disables the event handler for Application.ThreadException.  That's important, it lets you debug exceptions.  To get your catch clause to work without a debugger, you'll have to add this statement to your Main() method, before the Run() call:

```
   Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.ThrowException);
```

It now does make more sense to write an event handler for AppDomain.Current.UnhandledException instead, you'll also get notified about unhandled exceptions in worker threads.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of this you can handle following event (which is the preferred way of handling unhandled application exceptions):

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (sender, e) => 
{  
    Application.Run(new CrashReporter(e.StackTrace.ToString())); 
}
Application.Run(new TestServer());
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you running on a 64 bit OS?  This sounds like the problem Hans Passant answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125876/what-happens-when-you-attempt-to-access-a-winforms-treeview-by-keyword-and-that-k/4125994#4125994).

Debugging can swallow errors on Form construction and Forms_Load in 64 bit CLR...

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this thing works? I mean, did this strategy work for you previously?

I use (and suggested way) this way to catch the unhandled exceptions globally:

```
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException +=
            new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
//then start the main form...
Application.Run(new TestServer());
```

Here is the documentation
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx

Answer (score -2):

CrashReporter is causing it. An uncaught exception in a catch statement will cause an uncaught exception. You need another try/catch in your catch and another fall back.