# C# is there a way to validate assemblies loaded?

Tags: c#, .net, load, .net-assembly

Is there a way in .NET to validate loaded assemblies and if needed prevent to load it?

I was trying to use `AsseblyLoad` event, but it seems to be swallowing exception according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12529025):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyLoad += OnAssemblyLoaded;
    var asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"path\to\assembly.dll");

    Console.WriteLine($"loaded {asm.GetName().Name}");            
    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static void OnAssemblyLoaded(object sender, AssemblyLoadEventArgs args)
{
    // DO CHECKs here            
    throw new Exception("invalid assebly");
}
```

In real project, I want to verify publisher due to licence rules. I'm missing the place where I can put my custom validation code before loading assembly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'reflection only' loading to allow you to access the assembly via reflection to do the verification before loading properly.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.reflectiononlyload?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: This would require create encapsulated way how to load assemblies (and optionally throw exception prevent to load it), i.e. static method. It would be great if you have all your plugins under your control. But, how can I check external dlls when loading their assemblies? That's why am I looking for solution closer to .NET - some way to inject my own verification code.

Comment: You don't check the external assemblies when loading, you use this method to verify their publisher (or other data) BEFORE loading them 'for real'.